# How to get a full address (0xdd7319d5cbeb72c20776809f23ea2b3ab1296144) of an ens(cahldee.eth) where this has NFTS

Tags: nft, ens

i'm retrieve the nfts from an ENS but i want to retrieve the address behind that ENS.
Irwing Tello

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer with [quicknode.com](https://www.quicknode.com/), you need to use the [Graph API](https://www.quicknode.com/graph-api) and this is the query where you can accomplish this goal:

Query:

```
query NFTsByENS($ensName:String!){ethereum{walletByENS(ensName:$ensName){address}}}
{
  "ensName": "cahldee.eth",
}
```

Variables:

```
{
  "ensName": "coltron.eth",
}
```

Irwing Tello

Disclosure: I'm a QuickNode fan.

Comment: You said to me you weren't affiliated to QuickNode but all your questions and answers seem related. Make sure you follow the site recommendations https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion.

Comment: Hello @Ismael, I greatly appreciate your suggestion. While my inquiries might revolve around quicknode.com, I want to emphasize that I'm thoroughly exploring all the offerings provided by the platform. I'll make sure to transparently disclose my enthusiasm for quicknode.com in any topic. Thank you once again for your feedback!